What do we know about integer solution(s) to $x^p+ay^p=1$, where $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is a fixed integer?
We know how to write the solution to the equation $x^2+ay^2=1$.
Due to a Theorem by Nagell the solution to $x^3+ay^3=1$ has at most two solutions.
What do we know about $x^p+a y^p=1$. Does this have at most two solutions?

More generally, Thue's Theorem from $1909$ says that there are only finitely many integer solutions of
$$
x^n-dy^n=1,
$$
provided $x^n - d y^n$ is irreducible.
M.A. Bennett has shown that
$$
|ax^n+by^n|=1
$$
has at most one solution in positive integers $(x,y)$, for all $n\ge 3$ and fixed integers $a,b$ with $ab\neq 0$.

Thank you .. May I get a reference for Bennett's result?

I think I got it. https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BD.pdf   The result works except for some finitely values of n where 16<n<348.

They have a paper later, which also finishes the case $16<n<348$. So it holds in general. Also, see this paper.

Indeed. Thank you again..
